# Save and access multidimensional arrays

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm working with multidimensional arrays for a users settings.

I create them as follows:

```
myGameSettings = {}
myGameSettings["core"] = {}

myGameSettings["core"].soundOn="Sound^true^onOf"
myGameSettings["core"].musicOn="Music^true^onOf"
```

than when user change the setting with "widget.newSwitch" I want to change the value accordingly. 
the problem is, when I try to save the value it creates a new multidimensional array instead of changing the existing one. I can confirm with print that my values are correct

```
print("setting: " .. "myGameSettings" .. "[" .. type .."]" .. "." .. setting)
myGameSettings[type].setting=tostring(switch.isOn)
```

print from the console `setting: myGameSettings[core].musicOn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
myGameSettings[type][setting]=tostring(switch.isOn)
```